# Почему возвращается неправильный размер char*

Tags: c++

Функция перевода строки в последовательность байт. Неправильно возвращает строку. Если строка `test` то выражение, которое с комментарием, показывает 8

```
char* str_to_binary (const char* str) {

    string bin;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
        bitset<8> b(s.c_str()[i]);
        bin += b.to_string();
    }

    char* c = new char[bin.length() + 1];
    strcpy(c, bin.c_str());
    // sizeof(c)/sizeof(char)
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Что такое переменная `s`? Я ее не вижу

Answer (score 3):

Ваше выражение `sizeof(c)/sizeof(char)` равно размеру указателя на `char` в размерах `char`, т.е. байтах. На обычной 32-разрядной платформе размер указателя 4 байта, на 64-разрядной - 8.

Кстати, в функцию вы передаете `const char * str`, а работаете с чем-то типа `string s`, нигде не объявленным...

Посчитать длину строки с завершающим нулевым символом (в стиле C) можно с помощью функции `strlen(char*)`

Comment: А как тогда вернуть количество символов в массиве `c`?

Comment: Вы сами выделяете `bin.length() + 1` байт, вот и размер...

Comment: `bin.length() + 1` вообще возвращает что-то вроде `1` или `2`. А насчет `string s` - ошибки копипаста

Comment: Что он возвращает - это второй вопрос :) Что вам вообще-то надо? Представим, что есть массив из 10 `char`, в который записана строка `"hello"`. Что бы вы хотели получить? 10 или 5?

Comment: 5. Дело в том, что вывод строки большой, что-то вроде `010101100100` а выводит 1

Comment: @Herrgott `ошибки копипаста` можно было исправить путем редактирования текста вопроса.

Comment: @Herrgott: не нужно использовать `strlen()` когда у вас есть объект `std::string`.  Вам нужно разбираться почему `bin.length()` у вас ноль возвращает. Для этого надо исправить "ошибки копипаста" и показать настоящий код, который приводит к `bin.length() == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ @Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/531836/23044) объясняет почему `sizeof(c)/sizeof(char)`, где `c` это указатель, возвращает размер типа указателя, а не длину С строки, на которую этот указатель может ссылаться.

Чтобы полностью избежать подобных ошибок, можно использовать `std::string` для ввода/вывода вместо `char*`. Например, чтобы получить из байтов строки биты ("01"-строки—представление байтов в двоичной системе):

```
#include <bitset>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

template<class UnaryFunction>
void str_to_bits(const std::string& str, UnaryFunction yield)
{
  for (unsigned char byte : str)
    yield(std::bitset<CHAR_BIT>(byte).to_string());
}
```

Пример вызова:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  str_to_bits("abcdefgh", [] (auto bits) {
      std::cout << bits << ' ';
    });
}
```

`auto` в `lambda` поддерживается только начиная с c++14:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 yield_bits.cxx && ./a.out
01100001 01100010 01100011 01100100 01100101 01100110 01100111 01101000
```

Ожидаемо коды букв в английском алфавите идут подряд (1, 10, 11, 100, 101 итд в двоичной системе).